# how to change my time format to custom format

Tags: c#, winforms

i am reading a text file which has a timeformat of 10:00 as 100000

and 10.30 as 103000.

I want to change this 103000 to 10:30 and 104500 as 10:45, I dont know how to do it.

Can anyone please help me.

There would be a great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at 'DateTime.TryParse'

DateTime parsedTime = DateTime.ParseExact ( @"103000", @"HHmmss", null );

Then you can print the date in any format you want.

string formatted = parsedTime.ToString ( "HH:mm:ss" );

Comment: It will not parse time in 24-hour format

Comment: You're right. Correcting my post. Thanks!

Comment: thks its changing this 103000 to 10.30 but its not working for 190000 its saying string was not recognized as a valid datetime

Comment: @Arshiya why not to try my code?

Comment: Yes. Lazyberezovsky pointed that out, and I just corrected my post.

Comment: how can i write am and pm for this both

Comment: lazyberezovsky was the first to provide this answer... Just saying...

Answer (score 4):

```
string text = "104500";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var formattedDate = date.ToString("HH:mm"); // "10:45"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string mytext = "103000";
int hour = int.Parse(mytext.Substring(0,2));
int minutes = int.Parse(mytext.Substring(2,2));
int seconds = int.Parse(mytext.Substring(4,2));
string formattedTime = int.hour.ToString() + ":" + int.minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0');
```